# Import python files from git submodule without sys.path.append

Tags: python, python-3.x, git

I have a git project ('submodule_folder') cloned as a submodule inside my git project ('my_project') with the following file structure:

```
my_project
    submodule_folder
        submodule_folder2
            __init__.py
            submodule_file.py
        file_to_import.py
    my_file1.py
    my_file2.py
```

I want to import 'file_to_import.py' from 'my_file1.py' but 'file_to_import.py' imports 'submodule_file.py'.

When doing the following import from 'my_file1.py' I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodule_folder2'`.

```
from submodule_folder import file_to_import
```

Using Python3, is there any way to do this import without writing `sys.path.append('submodule_folder/')` in each of my files? I'd prefer not to modify the content of 'submodule_folder'.

Answer (score 0):

If `file_to_import.py` has

```
from submodule_folder2 import submodule_file
```

it worked in Python 2 because in Py2 it was implicit relative import. Python 3 disabled this import mode, it only allows absolute import or explicit relative import. Either

```
from submodule_folder.submodule_folder2 import submodule_file
```

or

```
from .submodule_folder2 import submodule_file
```

Comment: ```from .submodule_folder2 import submodule_file``` doesn't work in my case.
A ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.submodule_folder2'; '__main__' is not a package``` is raised.

Comment: For the second alternative I get different error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. First one won't work lol